# Bind Select Dropdown in Angular with Static Object Array in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I am binding Select DropDown with my static data.

**ProffesionModel.ts**

```
export interface Proffesion {
    id : number;
    title : string;
}
```

**app.PeopleListService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Proffesion } from "../model/proffessionModel";

@Injectable()
export class PeopleService {
  proffesions : Proffesion[] = [
    {id : 1, title : "Teacher"},
    {id : 2, title : "Engineer"},
    {id : 3, title : "Doctor"}
  ];

  constructor() { }
  getAllProffession() : Proffesion[]{
    return this.proffesions;
  }
}
```

**app.addperson.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Proffesion } from "../model/proffessionModel";
import { PeopleService } from "../services/app.peopleListService";

@Component({
    selector: 'add-person',
    templateUrl: 'addperson/app.addperson.html'
})

export class AddPersonComponent { 
    proffesion : Proffesion [];
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private peopleService:PeopleService){
        this.proffesion = peopleService.getAllProffession();
    }
}
```

**app.addperson.html**

```
<section>
    <form (ngSubmit)="savePerson()" #personForm="ngForm">
      <div>
        <label for="profession">Profession: </label>
        <select name="proffesion" [(ngModel)]="person.proffesion" #proffesion="ngModel">
          <option *ngFor="let p of proffesion" [value]="p.id">{{p.title}}</option>
        </select>
        </div>
      <div>
       <button type="submit" [disabled]="!personForm.form.valid">Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
<button (click)="gotoPeoplesList()">Back to peoples list</button>
```

I am getting following error when my addperson page get load.

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in addperson/app.addperson.html:28:18 caused by: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'proffesion'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: why you are using word `proffesion` so many times like for `arrayName` for `localVariableName` for binding in ngMOdel ?

Comment: it was not intentionally. I am just learning Angular2 so didn't know exactly naming conversation

Comment: okay NP, just try using different name , may cause same error, if not helped then please try console your array in the component

Comment: ok. i change the name of the localvariableName and its working. :) silly I am

Comment: @Vega : I have not mentioned that part here in code for simplicity and readability of the required code

Comment: NP man, glad to know its working now ;) , you can mark my answer as acceted ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using word `proffesion` so many times like for `arrayName` for `localVariableName` for `binding in ngMOdel`

May be because you are assigning same name in `ngModel` too.

So avoid same name everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this in template

```
<select [(ngModel)]="person.proffesion"  >
    <option *ngFor=" let object of list_object"  value="{{object.id}}">
      {{object.name}}
     </option>
</select>
```

also refer this post 
[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/0KrhA94WgKgY9pp4T35O?p=preview)